# How to displace a segmented line along a sine wave with Shader Graph?

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I have a mesh made of three identical cylinders (conceptually just line segments with a non-zero thickness) crossed over each other at 60 degree angles, so the ends describe the points of a regular hexagon.  The cylinders are divided into a lot of segments, which I'd like to displace in a sinewave pattern.  The pivot is in the center of the mesh.

My concept is pretty straightforward:

- Subtract object position from vertex position to get vertex position relative to the pivot (VPR).
- Normalize VPR and swap the X and Y to get a vector in the XY plane perpendicular to the orientation of the cylinder.
- Take the magnitude of VPR, multiply by a V1 parameter (Waviness), then take the sine.
- Multiply the sine by the perpendicular orientation vector to get the displacement.
- Add the displacement to the vertex position.  Assign result to master node's vertex position.

This really feels like it should work.  Each cylinder should be distorted along a sine wave, with the magnitude of the distortion increasing the further it gets from the center, so I end up with three wavy lines crossed over each other at 60 degree angles.  Increasing `Waviness` should increase the frequency of the wave, as the base value is multiplied by it before feeding into the sine node.

Instead, things curve just a little bit at a low `Waviness`, but as I increase it the cylinders get both thicker and longer, neither of which should be happening, and start wrapping themselves around the mesh in weird patterns.  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong!

Here's my graph setup, with the mesh assigned to the preview so you can see what a mess it's making of it:
[image]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure about all of the strange effects you're describing, but one thing I think could be causing problems is the scale of tings. Because waviness modifies the input to sine, and it's >1, it will always make the spatial frequency of the sine higher. Now, the input to trig functions is usually given in radians, so you'll have one oscillation per 2*Pi = 6.28 units. Depending on how big the cylinders are, and how fine or coarse the mesh is, you may be experiencing some aliasing problems (e.g., the wavelength might be shorter than the distance between the vertices).

Comment: So, one thing you could do to see what's going on is to temporarily replace waviness with a simple scaling factor. E.g., if you want 1 wavelength across 100 units, you need a scaling factor of `s = 2*Pi/(wavelength) = 2*Pi/100`. Once you figure out the scale, you can map it to the more intuitive-to-use waviness, by mapping the max and min waviness to the max and min scaling factor (look up "two-point form line equation"). Essentially, multiply input waviness `w` by `m*(w-wMin) + sMin`, where `m` is the slope `(sMax-sMin)/(wMax-wMin)` (maybe there's a node that does that for you).

Comment: Also, because for the displacement you use the normalized vector, the magnitude of the distortion will be the same along the cylinder, and it will be between -1 and 1. You don't need to normalize the vector, but you may want to introduce a separate scaling factor for it. I'm not sure why the cylinders are getting longer, though.

Comment: "multiply input waviness `w` by `m*(w-wMin) + sMin`" - sorry, I didn't mean to say multiply, I meant apply that formula - but I just looked it up, you can use the Remap Node for that.